# Breaking a while loop after every fourth result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a new row or breaking my row of results to drop down to a new row in my results set because at the moment they just go on and on and break out of the container and do not create a new row as it hits the end of the container.

My code is fairly simple - I am using the bulma css framework and specifically the `is-3` class to display each result so its gives me 4 columns in the container. So after every four a new row should be created.

My code is is fairly simple:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="columns projectList">
    <?php while($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <div class="column is-3">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
        <p class="projectStatus">
        <?php
        if($phase == 0){
            echo 'Phase: Pending';
        } 
        elseif($phase == 1){
            echo 'Phase: Planning';
        }
        elseif($phase == 2){
            echo 'Phase: Design';
        }  
        elseif($phase == 4){
            echo 'Phase: Development';
        }
        else{
            echo 'No Phase Added';
        }           
        ?>
        </p>
        <p class="projectTitle"><span>!</span><?php echo $projectName; ?></p>
            <div class="projectTimes">
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="days">12</span>
                    <span class="for">Days Left In Design</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="days">42</span>
                    <span class="for">Days to finish</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
        <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8EF;</i>32</a>
        <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0B9;</i>10</a>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END ROW HERE AND CREATE NEW ONE -->
    <?php } $stmt->close(); } ?>
</div>  
</div>
```

My question: How do I line break after every fourth result?

Comment: `So after every four a new row should be created.` ? WHICH NEW ROW YOU ARE TALKING ABOUT? CAN YOU POINT OUT IN YOUR CODE?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have amended my code and added a note in

Comment: So you want records coming from  `<?php while($stmt->fetch()) { ?>` will break in 4-4 section?(the whole `<div class="column is-3">`)

Comment: set $i=1 before loop, incriment inside the loop, just after while statement use if($i%4==0){ add your new row div} at the end close that div just before your while closing

Comment: @Santosh and example of this would be great so I can understand your approach

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you're just juggling some CSS every 4 rows, to make it a new row instead of a column, you should be able to do it with pure CSS3 using something like the `:nth-of-type(4n)` selector: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

Comment: How you like line break on and `nth` pseudo selector?

Comment: Depends on what's actually going on with the the `is-3` class - it could be something as simple as `clear: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
    <div class="container">

            <?php 
        $x = 1;
        while($stmt->fetch()) { 

        ?>
           <?php if($x == 1) { ?> <div class="columns projectList"> <?php }
  $x++;
 ?>
            <div class="column is-3">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                <div class="content">
                <p class="projectStatus">
                <?php
                if($phase == 0){
                    echo 'Phase: Pending';
                } 
                elseif($phase == 1){
                    echo 'Phase: Planning';
                }
                elseif($phase == 2){
                    echo 'Phase: Design';
                }  
                elseif($phase == 4){
                    echo 'Phase: Development';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'No Phase Added';
                }           
                ?>
                </p>
                <p class="projectTitle"><span>!</span><?php echo $projectName; ?></p>
                    <div class="projectTimes">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="days">12</span>
                            <span class="for">Days Left In Design</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="days">42</span>
                            <span class="for">Days to finish</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="card-footer">
                <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8EF;</i>32</a>
                <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0B9;</i>10</a>
                </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END ROW HERE AND CREATE NEW ONE -->
            <?php
          if($x % 4 == 0)
        {
         echo '<div/>';
         $x = 1;
        }
         } $stmt->close(); } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Using modulo (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is much more elegant.
e.g., `if($x % 4 == 0) { echo '<br />'; }`.

Comment: Im arfaid not, this seems to be production the same result and jumping out the container still...

Comment: @danjbh post the static html ? what the output html would be like.

Comment: Ok I got it, It needs to create a new class `columns` and then `column is-3` is the new rows. There is far too much html to post out when showing a demo of it, but the framework needs to create a new row by using columns again with the column is-3 inside of columns in order to create a new row.

Comment: @danjbh check the updated code i think this is wat you want.

Comment: So with this method, the first two in the row display ok, but then the two after are squashed

Comment: did you inspect the html weather its ok or not ?

Comment: the class `columns` is what creates a new row.

Comment: @danjbh i think there is an extra bracket at the end can you plz check 
 } $stmt->close(); } ?>

it should be  } $stmt->close();  ?>
i think.

Comment: @Santosh i assure u its not. i was jst trying to help . if u think like that there is nothing i can do. i use stackoverflow to help and learn myself.

Comment: tnx @Catalyst i refined the answer with your modulo , i hope u don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">


    <?php 
    $i = 0;
     while($stmt->fetch()) { 
   if($i%4==0){
        echo '<div class="columns projectList">';
    }
    $i++;
  ?>
    <div class="column is-3">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
        <p class="projectStatus">
        <?php
        if($phase == 0){
            echo 'Phase: Pending';
        } 
        elseif($phase == 1){
            echo 'Phase: Planning';
        }
        elseif($phase == 2){
            echo 'Phase: Design';
        }  
        elseif($phase == 4){
            echo 'Phase: Development';
        }
        else{
            echo 'No Phase Added';
        }           
        ?>
        </p>
        <p class="projectTitle"><span>!</span><?php echo $projectName; ?></p>
            <div class="projectTimes">
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="days">12</span>
                    <span class="for">Days Left In Design</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <span class="days">42</span>
                    <span class="for">Days to finish</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
        <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8EF;</i>32</a>
        <a class="card-footer-item"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0B9;</i>10</a>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
     if($i%4==0){
        echo '</div>'
        $i = 0;
    }
  ?>
    <!-- END ROW HERE AND CREATE NEW ONE -->
    <?php } $stmt->close(); } ?>

</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing also? Am I placing it in the wrong section? So maybe it needs to go outside of column?

Comment: replace with my code and try also you can do anything in  if($i == 4){ //here(line break or div ) $i = 0;}

Comment: in this case modulo and $i == 4 are same

Comment: Ok I got it, It needs to create a new class `columns` and then `column is-3` is the new rows.

Comment: you can also add class where ever you want base on that condition get it?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called the `modulus`.

```
for ($c = 1; $c < count($results); $c++) {
    if ($c % 4 == 0) {
        // This is the fourth iteration
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, This is something I cam e across before on another thread... I tried to implement it but perhaps I put it in the wrong place? Could you advise me should this go outside of the while loop or inside?

Comment: this will go your inside loop check your last comment in post.

Comment: Ok I got it, It needs to create a new class `columns` and then `column is-3` is the new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using this logic you can break your ROW at fourth iteration

```
$i = 0; 
while(while($stmt->fetch())){

  if($i%4==0){
       //div to create new ROW
  }

  <div class="column is-3">
    //all your logic go here
  </div>

  if($i%4==0){
       // close the div for create new ROW
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple one. I take from your question that you essentially want to split your results from the query into groups of 3? With each group being displayed as a row?

What i would recommened is fetching all of your results at once and storing as a variable. Assuming this variable is an array you can use **array_chunk()** to split the array of rows into the cunks you need. This will result in an array of arrays with each of the inner arrays containing the specified number of items. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Ive mocked up a quick example for you here:

```
<?php 

//Fetch all data, this will become the $items array
$items = array(
    'item 1', 
    'item 2', 
    'item 3',
    'item 4',
    'item 5',
    'item 6',
    'item 7',
    'item 8',
    'item 9',
    'item 10',
    'item 11',
    'item 12',
    'item 13',
    'item 14',
);

//Split the items into 'rows' (chunks)
//The second parameter here basically indiciates how many items you want in each row
$rows = array_chunk($items, 3);

//Loop over each row group, remembering each row is an array of items (columns)
//Do your row building HTML within this foreach loop
//Do your columnd building HTML within the inner foreach loop 
foreach($rows as $columns){
    echo "---------------<br />";

    //Build column html for each item within the row
    foreach($columns as $column){
         echo $column.' | ';   
    }

    echo "<br />";
    echo "---------------";
    echo "<br /><br />";
}

?>
```

Run the abover here: http://phpfiddle.org/

You can see how it splits up the rows etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is confusing because it has very little correlation with me own code I am early in my learning at the moment I will try and study this.

Comment: The solution provides only the logic required to split your data in rows containing a certain number of columns. My echo statements are only to show data output, you should replace these with the html provided in your question.